# Provide/Inject and change of injected variable

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I provide variables in a component and inject/change them in the child component of it. This works fine on the local server but uploaded to the server, the variable doesn't seem to change.

I use composition API.

### Component A (parent)

```
import { provide, ref } from 'vue';

const loggedIn = ref(false);
provide('global', loggedIn);

const credentials = ref(true);
provide('credentials', credentials);
```

### Component B (child)

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  IonContent,
  IonHeader,
  IonPage,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
} from "@ionic/vue";

import router from "@/router";

import { inject, ref } from "vue";

const global: boolean = inject("global") as boolean;

const credentials: boolean = inject("credentials") as boolean;


function greet(global: boolean, credentials: boolean) {
  
  const usr = document.querySelector("input[name=email]").value;

  const pass = document.querySelector("input[name=password]").value;
  if (
    usr === "guest@guest.com" &&
    pass === "guest123#"
  ) {
    
    this.global = true;

    this.credentials = false;

    router.push("/app");
  }
}


</script>
```

VS Code shows two warnings for both this.global = true and this.credentials = false:

```
'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
HomePage.vue(19, 10): An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.
```

Any ideas of how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Injections` are not reactive by default.

You can make your `injections` reactive using a `computed` property. Check the [Provide / Inject: ​​Working with Reactivity](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity) section.

2. Injections are like `props` and `readonly`.

You can change the injected value in the child component, but the change will not be send to the parent.

Check the provided Vue [SFC Playground Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) to clarify it.

The solution is to use a custom store or Vuex/[Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).

Here is the updated [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

Message2 gets updated only in the GrandChild, nub but not in the parent App.